# Attributes set with setattr show as unresolved references in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

I have a class that defines several attributes dynamically using `setattr` builtin. However, all uses of those attributes are shown as unresolved references by PyCharm. Is there a way (via code or PyCharm setting) to help PyCharm resolved those attributes?

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately you can not.

From my point of view, you can ignore the warning doing Alt + Enter on your dynamic attribute and then selecting "Ignore unresolved reference".

Or, if you don't want do it for all class attributes, you can add @DynamicAttrs in the class docstring.

Here an example:

```
class YourClassWithSeveralAttributes(object):
    """@DynamicAttrs""" # <-- here

    def __init__(self):
        setattr(self, 'foo', 1)
        setattr(self, 'bar', 2)
        setattr(self, 'foo1', 11)
        setattr(self, 'bar2', 22)
```

Keep in mind that none of previous solutions will make PyCharm able to recognize your dynamic attributes and the autocompletition feature will be not available for those attributes. They are just way to ignore the warnings.

Comment: `@DynamicAttrs` is just great! It also works if I add it to the doc string in the parent class that calls the `setattr`. I can live with the drawback that in this and derived classes the "Unresolved reference" warnings are not active.

Comment: Is there also a way to hint attributes via docstring, such that they are available for auto-completion and to avoid warnings? Similar to the `@DynamicAttrs` keyword.

Comment: I don't know anything like this, sorry.

Comment: @matheburg With Python 3.6+ you can add class-level type hints which will enable auto-completion. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49052572/7446465)

Answer (score 0):

Try `File` --> `Invalidate Caches / Restart` --> `Invalidate and Restart`